# convert duplicate links to references in markdown

Tags: github, reference, markdown, jekyll

How to convert duplicate links to references in markdown? Rather than duplicate the same link many times in markdown, it would be much better to use a reference.

Comment: You need to clarify: Are you asking for *how to use* reference links in markdown, or *how to automate* said conversion?

Answer (score 2):

1. [How to use referenced-style links](https://commonmark.org/help/) (See Link and Image examples)
2. [How to convert inline links to referenced-style links using Pandoc](https://raymii.org/s/articles/Convert_markdown_inline_links_to_reference_style_links_with_Pandoc.html)